# Meaning and structure of "The vision to do today what is needed for tomorrow."

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

I would like to know the structure of the sentence and also meaning.
Is the vision subject?  What in the sentence is what?

> The vision to do today what is needed for tomorrow.

Can I understand.. like this?

*the vision we do today is what we need for tomorrow.*

The sentence was part of a speech as follow.

> Reject pessimism and fatalism. Refuse limits on our spirations. To do that, we need to have the imagination and confidence to do things differently and better. The vision to do today what is needed for tomorrow.

Comment: It's not actually a complete sentence. It's a noun phrase, implicitly describing another thing we "need to have."

Comment: Per @alphabet for reference. And for meaning, you are trying to say that "We need a vision so wise that we will now do everything we will need to have for the future."

Comment: Oxford Languages' second definition of **vision** is _the ability to think about or plan the future with imagination or wisdom._

Comment: Best way to understand it is "We need to have the vision to do today what is needed for tomorrow." Or "...we need to have the imagination and confidence to do things differently and better and the vision to do today what is needed for tomorrow", though that's confusing due to the frequency of "and", hence the alternative structure.

Comment: Perhaps worth attributing to [Rishi Sunak in a piece in  *The Spectator*](https://www.spectator.co.uk/article/my-vision-for-a-better-future/) 4 Jan 2023.  He is claiming that he sees what will be needed in future and that he is acting now in anticipation of that.  Whether that is correct is a political question.

Answer (score 1):

> Reject pessimism and fatalism. Refuse limits on our aspirations. To do that, we need to have the imagination and confidence to do things differently and better. The vision to do today what is needed for tomorrow.

Rephrasing with different punctuation:

> To do that, we need to have the imagination and confidence to do things differently and better — the vision to do today what is needed for tomorrow.

**the vision to do today what is needed for tomorrow** is a restatement, using different words, an elaboration of **the imagination and confidence to do things differently and better**. The two noun phrases are more or less synonymous.

P.S. In writing that tends towards oratory, as this does, you will often find what appear to be sentence-fragments, to judge by the punctuation.  But the punctuation in such writing is often more about pauses for effect than it is about demarcating the internal clause structure within the sentence.